# slideToogle not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't get this effect to work as it should, what might be the issue? IT doesn't open and close, in the JS fiddle it works.

I have absolutely no idea why it doesn't work. The Jquery is implemented properly. (Since my google maps code is working). I'm calling the scripts file. This is making me insane. :D

************************EDIT***************************************

So I found the issue, my GMaps code is conflictiong with this code, if I comment ot GMaps everything works fine. I just have to find a way around this now.

```
<nav>
                   <div class="nav-container  js--top-nav">
                    <ul class="top-nav">
                        <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                        <li><a href="services.html">SERVICES</a></li>
                        <li><a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
                    </ul>
                   </div>
                    <a class="mobile-nav-icon js--nav-icon"><i class="ion-navicon "></i></a>

</nav>
```

And the JS

```
$('.js--nav-icon').click(function() {
   var nav = $('.js--top-nav');

   nav.slideToggle(200);

});
```

Comment: Seems to work fine in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2c5vkkqo/. Can you provide some actual detail about what you expect to happen, and what the problem is.

Comment: Anything in console?

Comment: Please post the specific behavior you are having and why it's wrong and how to recreate it if applicable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @TacoCat if my asumption is right, what you want is to stop the flickering of the div while toggling. then do one thing in your js. Replace this "var nav = $('.js--top-nav');"  as "var nav = $('.top-nav');"    http://jsfiddle.net/2c5vkkqo/4/

Answer (score 1):

Are you putting your code inside $(document).ready()?
Please try like this:-

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.js--nav-icon').click(function() {
    var nav = $('.js--top-nav');

   nav.slideToggle(200);
    });

   });
```

Comment: Yes I am, I found out the answer, my google maps code was conflicting the code, now I just have to find a way around it. When I comment out the GM code everything works fine.

Comment: @TacoCat just a suggestion, change the var nav = $('.js--top-nav'); to var nav = $('.top-nav');. your code flickers the div while toggling.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated *"I can't get this effect to work as it should"*. If my asumption is right, what you want is to stop the flickering of the div while toggling. then do one thing in your js. 
Replace this

```
var nav = $('.js--top-nav');
```

to

```
var nav = $('.top-nav'); // toggle the ul instead of the div
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2c5vkkqo/4/